# How i can remove key/value from a list of tuples by key from another list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need to remove keys and values in a list of tuples by keys from another list of tuples

```py
list_tuple = [('NHR', 153.065), ('BHS', 153.179), ('KMH', 153.393), ('DRR', 287.987), ('SSW', 487.294), ('EOF', 546.972), ('LHM', 687.54)]

list_tuple_keys = [('DRR', 'Error time'), ('EOF', 'Error time'), ('LHM', 'Error time'), ('SSW', 'Error time')]

example = [('NHR', 153.065), ('BHS', 153.179), ('KMH', 153.393)]
```

Comment: Make your question understandable please

Comment: Remove multiple example. Just give one desired output.

Comment: If you name your variables `given`, `keys_to_remove` and `expected_output`, the code will be easier to understand.

Comment: `[t for t in list_tuple if not any(t[0] == r[0] for r in list_tuple_keys)]`

Answer (score 0):

Given the code

```py
given = [('NHR', 153.065), ('BHS', 153.179), ('KMH', 153.393), ('DRR', 287.987), ('SSW', 487.294), ('EOF', 546.972), ('LHM', 687.54)]
to_remove = [('DRR', 'Error time'), ('EOF', 'Error time'), ('LHM', 'Error time'), ('SSW', 'Error time')]
expected = [('NHR', 153.065), ('BHS', 153.179), ('KMH', 153.393)
```

I'd first reduce the list of items to remove to just the minimum information needed:

```py
keys = []
for item in to_remove:
    keys.append(item[0])
```

or `keys = [t[0] for t in to_remove]` as a list comprehension.

Then you can go through the list of items to be filtered and skip the unwanted ones:

```py
result = []
for item in given:
    if not item[0] in keys:
        result.append(item)
```

or `result = [t for t in given if not t[0] in keys]` as a list comprehension.

Finally

```py
print(result)
```

results in

```
[('NHR', 153.065), ('BHS', 153.179), ('KMH', 153.393)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a hashmap for filtering target list.

```
filter_keys = {t[0]: True for t in list_tuple_keys}
result = [t for t in list_tuple if not filter_keys.get(t[0], False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with list comprehension

```
result = [item for item in list_tuple if item[0] not in dict(list_tuple_keys)]

# result
[('NHR', 153.065), ('BHS', 153.179), ('KMH', 153.393)]
```

Converted `list_tuple_keys` into a dictionary, so it's easy to check the membership.